# Salvar imagem com webservice

Tags: imagem

Eu já tenho um webservice para o qual eu passo um imagem (Base64) e ele salva no meu servidor. Até aqui ele está funcionando perfeitamente.

**Na minha tela tem esse código :**

```
function salvar() {
        var dados = {};

        //Utilizar o toDataURL para converter em Base64
        var base64 = document.getElementById("myCanvas").toDataURL("image/png");

        dados.base64 = base64.substr(base64.indexOf(',') + 1, base64.length);

        var WPath = "face1";

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            //Chamar o webmethod SalvarImagem em webservice.asmx
            url: "SalvarImagem.asmx/SalvarImagemX",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(dados, WPath),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            }
            , error: function (xmlHttpRequest, status, err) {
                alert("Ocorreu o seguinte erro:" + xmlHttpRequest.responseText)
            }
        });
    }
```

**E o meu webservice está assim :**

```
public class SalvarImagem : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string SalvarImagemX(string base64, string WPath)
    {
           //MemoryStream com o base64 recebido por parâmetro
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64)))
        {
            //Criar um novo Bitmap baseado na MemoryStream
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms))
            {
                //Local onde vamos salvar a imagem (raiz do site + /canvas.png)
                //string path = Server.MapPath("/" + WPath + "/canvas.png");
                string path = Server.MapPath("/face2/canvas.png");

                //Salvar a imagem no formato PNG
                bmp.Save(path, ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }

        return "Imagem foi salva com sucesso";
    }
}
}
```

Meu problemas está que : Como eu disse ele funciona enquanto eu passo somente um paramentro que é a string DADOS. Mas eu preciso passar também outra string que contem a pasta onde deve ser gravado a imagem...

Quando eu coloquei segundo parâmetro (WPath) eu passei a receber a mensagem de erro abaixo... Alguem sabe me dizer o que tem de errado ....??

Ocorreu o seguinte erro:

> {"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter:
>   \u0027WPath\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object
>   target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object
>   target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quem interessar possa o problema era porque estava faltando colocar o complemento da variavel, estava assim :

```
data: '{"base64":"' + dados + '","fileName":"' + nomearq + '"}',
```

Mas o certo é assim : `data: '{"base64":"' + dados.base64 + '","fileName":"' + nomearq + '"}',`

Fica o registro para futuros sofredores.
Abs.

Answer (score 1):

Está dando erro porque não é assim que se usa o `JSON.stringify` para o que você está pretendendo.

Você passou dois parâmetros pra ele, aqui:

`JSON.stringify(dados, WPath)`

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), o segundo parâmetro do `JSON.stringify` é o `replacer`:

> replacer: A function that alters the behavior of the stringification
>   process, or an array of String and Number objects that serve as a
>   whitelist for selecting/filtering the properties of the value object
>   to be included in the JSON string.

Em uma tradução livre, o `replacer` seria "Uma função que altera o comportamento do processo de transformação em string, ou um array de String e Number que servem como uma lista para selecionar e filtrar as propriedades do objeto a ser transformado em string".

Eu ia te mostrar como usar o segundo parâmetro, mas não foi essa a pergunta, então vou deixar uma possível solução para o seu AJAX. Troque o código que eu mencionei a cima, pelo seguinte:

```
data: '{"base64":"' + dados + '","WPath":"' + WPath + '"}'
```

Espero que te ajude, qualquer dúvida coloca aí nos comentários

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado Diego...

Nãotenho muito experiência com AJAX ei fiz o que você sugeriu mas está dando um erro de sintaxe que eu não consigo identificar... segue imagem..

[image: erro]

Comment: Ok.. já descobri... faltava uma ',' no final...

Comment: Olá, não poste dúvidas adicionais como resposta, em vez disso, coloque um comentário em uma resposta que gerou a dúvida. A minha resposta ajudou? Então marque-a como aceita. Você também pode votar em outras perguntas e respostas no site

Comment: Ola fiz o que você sugeriu e passou a dará esse erro...Ocorreu o seguinte erro:{"Message":"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.